# Itemsource Binding Unique for each row in DataGridComboBox C#

Tags: c#, wpf, datagridcomboboxcolumn, itemsource

I have this problem, and I appreciate if you help me with it.
I have a ViewModel with `public ObservableCollection<IProfile> Profiles { get; set; }` Property which fills a DataGrid. 
Inside the DataGrid, there is a ComboBox Column:

```
     <DataGridComboBoxColumn 
                    Header="Header"
                    Width="*"
                    Visibility="{Binding SelectedType, Converter={Commons:ProfileVisibilityConverter}}"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding PotentialReinforces}"
                    SelectedValueBinding="{Binding SectionID, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus, Mode=TwoWay}"
                    DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                    SelectedValuePath="ReinforceID"/>
```

I cannot use a static ItemSource since each row's ComboBox source is different compared to other rows. Therefore, I need dynamic ItemSource 
Inside the Profile Class I have defined the PotentialReinforces as below and it provides a suitable result for each object:

```
        public ObservableCollection<Section> PotentialReinforces
        {
            get
            {
                var Ids = this != null ? Database.Reinforces.Get.Where(x => x.BlongID == this.SectionID).Select(x => x.SectionID.Value) : new int[0];
                if (Ids.Count() > 0)
                {
                    return new ObservableCollection<Section>(Database.ReinforceSections.Get.Where(x => Ids.Contains(x.SectionID)));
                }
                else return null;
            }
        }
```

When I debug the code, each Profile object has the potential collection according to my design but the Combobox doesn't recognize the collection as its ItemSource.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem using an alteration on `DataGridComboBoxColumn` which I learned from Joe on this [page](http://joemorrison.org/blog/2009/02/17/excedrin-headache-35401281-using-combo-boxes-with-the-wpf-datagrid/). This simply defines a new type of DataGridComboBoxColumn which solves the problem.

```
    public class DataGridComboBoxColumnWithBindingHack : DataGridComboBoxColumn
    {
        protected override FrameworkElement GenerateEditingElement(DataGridCell cell, object dataItem)
        {
            FrameworkElement element = base.GenerateEditingElement(cell, dataItem);
            CopyItemsSource(element);
            return element;
        }

        protected override FrameworkElement GenerateElement(DataGridCell cell, object dataItem)
        {
            FrameworkElement element = base.GenerateElement(cell, dataItem);
            CopyItemsSource(element);
            return element;
        }

        private void CopyItemsSource(FrameworkElement element)
        {
            BindingOperations.SetBinding(element, ComboBox.ItemsSourceProperty,
              BindingOperations.GetBinding(this, ComboBox.ItemsSourceProperty));
        }
    }
```

```
 <Commons:DataGridComboBoxColumnWithBindingHack 
                    Header="Header"
                    Width="*"
                    Visibility="{Binding SelectedType, Converter={Commons:ProfileVisibilityConverter}}"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding PotentialReinforces}"
                    SelectedValueBinding="{Binding ReinforceID, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"
                    DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                    SelectedValuePath="SectionID"/>
```